# spark streaming rate source generate rows too slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, performance-testing, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark [RateStreamSource](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/content/spark-sql-streaming-RateStreamSource.html) to generate massive data per second for a performance test.

To test I actually get the amount of concurrency I want, I have set the **rowPerSecond** option to a high number 10000,

```py
    df = (
        spark.readStream.format("rate")
        .option("rowPerSecond", 100000)
        .option("numPartitions", 100)
        .load()
    )
```

However,  when I run my pyspark script locally,  the row generation is very slow. (less than 1 row per second)

I printed out the result, as you can see from the log extract below, the row count is 142 after about a minute

> Row content:  Row(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 6, 23, 36, 15, 16000), value=142)

So my question is:

- Why is the rate source not working as I expected, does it have anything to do since I run it locally?
- How can I increase the concurrency locally with my spark job?

Comment: FYI, I tried to run the same code on Databricks cluster with 4 workers, 16core each, the concurrency did not increase much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the option - it should be `rowsPerSecond`.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for pointing it out.